# 404: Is there any way to avoid being blocked by website while scraping using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I was trying to use Scrapy to scrape some website about 70k items. but every time after it scraped about 200 items, theis error will pop up for the rest:

```
scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <404 http://www.somewebsite.com/1234>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

I believe it is because my spider got blocked by the website, and I tried using random user agent suggested [here](http://tangww.com/2013/06/UsingRandomAgent/) but it doesn't solve the problem at all. Is there any good suggestions?

Comment: For me the best workaround for these kind of situations is using `Kimono Labs` you can scrape literally anything and create an API and let them worry about Ban situation you get data in JSON which you can simply get by hitting their API

Answer (score 1):

If you're being blocked your spider is probably hitting the site too often or too fast.

In addition to a random user agent you can try setting the CONCURRENT_REQUESTS and DOWNLOAD_DELAY options in settings.py. The default is fairly aggressive and will hammer a site.

The other options you have are using proxies or use AWS with nano instances, they get a new IP each reboot.

Remember that scraping is at best a gray area, you absolutely need to respect the site owners. The best way is obviously to seek permission from the owner but failing that you need to make sure your scraping efforts don't stand out from the usual browsing patterns or you'll get blocked in no time.

Some sites use fairly sophisticated techniques to identify scrapers including cookies and javascript as well as just request patterns and time on site etc. There are also a number of cloud based anti-scraping solutions such as distil or shieldsquare which if you're up against you'll need to put in a lot of effort to make your spider look human!

Comment: tried both CONCURRENT_REQUESTS and DOWNLOAD_DELAY still doesn't work, I'm basically trying to scrape resumes from indeed, is that feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you force someone to answer your questions or give you information?  Neither can you force a web server.  At best you can try to impersonate a client that the web server will answer to.  To do that you need to figure out the criteria the server uses to decide whether or not to answer the request, then you can (try to) form a request that will meet the criteria.